# npm refuses to install grunt dependencies

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm

I have a few projects using grunt and today npm refuses to install the dependencies.

One important point.. this used to work fine, just stopped all of a sudden.

The package file is conform to the grunt docs (http://gruntjs.com/getting-started#package.json)

```
{
  "name": "devproject",
  "author": "me",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.6.2",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.2",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.1",
    "grunt-sass": "~0.10.0"
  }
}
```

if I run `npm install`, instead of installing the devDependencies, npm now gives those 3 warnings:

```
npm WARN package.json devproject@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json devproject@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json devproject@1.0.0 No README data
```

And nothing happens, the dependencies aren't installed.

I could add a description and readme if I had too, but it makes no sense to have a repository settting, this is a private build script inside a folder in another repo.

If i add `"private" : true,` to the `package.json` file, then the warnings disappear but nothing happen, still no installation.

If I run `npm -verbose install`, I get this:

```
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ 'node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', '-verbose', 'install' ]
npm info using npm@1.4.6
npm info using node@v0.10.26
npm verb node symlink /usr/local/bin/node
npm verb readDependencies using package.json deps
npm verb install where, deps [ '/Users/me/dev/sites/devproject/public/wp-content/themes/devproject/resources',
npm verb install   [] ]
npm info preinstall devproject@1.0.0
npm verb readDependencies using package.json deps
npm info build /Users/me/dev/sites/devproject/public/wp-content/themes/devproject/resources
npm verb linkStuff [ false,
npm verb linkStuff   false,
npm verb linkStuff   false,
npm verb linkStuff   '/Users/me/dev/sites/devproject/public/wp-content/themes/devproject' ]
npm info linkStuff devproject@1.0.0
npm verb linkBins devproject@1.0.0
npm verb linkMans devproject@1.0.0
npm verb rebuildBundles devproject@1.0.0
npm info install devproject@1.0.0
npm info postinstall devproject@1.0.0
npm info prepublish devproject@1.0.0
npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
npm info ok
```

Again, this used to work fine. I haven't changed my config since. The only thing I can think of i that i install browsersync a couple of days ago. I've tried removing it but it hasn't changed anything.

Any clue?

Comment: Weird. Maybe delete `node_modules` and run install again?

Comment: yeah, nothing happens.. it's kinda like it assumes production environment but it isn't set to production (as far as I know, `npm config ls -l` says `production = false`)

Comment: i just started noticing my `npm install` and `npm update` are not installing devDependencies by default too ... and the same with `npm config ls -l` showing `production = false`, `NODE_ENV` is not set, etc.

Comment: Any updates on this? I have the same problem while deploying on heroku.